# How to link xml file and java to my node js?

Tags: java, xml, bluetooth, webapp2, nodejs-server

I am an IT trainee and my boss assigned me to make a code in which the web application that we're developing will scan the Bluetooth status (if it is on or off) of the user's device. I looked about the sample codes in the net but most of them shows for Android app. Those codes are in xml file and java but I'm using node js and JavaScript. So now, if I'm going to use xml and java, how can I integrate them with my node js?
I hope my question is clear. Thanks!